# pip ssl certificate not being validated

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, pip

I am currently attempting to use `python3` on *centos7* instance. I understand that it comes with python2.7 already installed, but as a requirement for the project I am working on I am needing a version of python3. I have python3 installed and as I am manually installing pip through the get-pip.py method (python3.4 doesn't come with pip when using on RHEL for some reason so I manually installed it) I get an arror. I originally ran into a proxy issue when trying to use pip, but got that worked out through an environment variable. Now I am getting the following error when i run `python get-pip.py` ...

```
Collecting pip
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```

A colleague of mine said that it still may be a proxy issue but I don't know and neither does anyone else on my team. Any suggestions?

Comment: what happens when you try to reach other HTTPS site with python?

Comment: @Ashafix same thing.. i cant do anything related to pip or easy_install.

Comment: You cannot open any pages which need SSL?

Comment: @Ashafix that is correct.

Comment: does it work in Python 2.7? we had something similar on a Red Hat server. Can you try `strace` together with your Python script?

Comment: @Ashafix I'm getting the same result in Python2.7...